# HighCharts losing all data when addPoint is called

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Background**

I have a HighCharts JS chart being updated every minute, but with the chart initially populated using the load event in the chart config.

My problem is that when I call addPoint on the series, the chart shifts all of it's data and leaves the chart with only the one new data point in the middle of the chart.

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(["Thu, 22 Sep 2016 13:21:58 GMT", 98], true, true)
chart.series[1].addPoint(["Thu, 22 Sep 2016 13:21:58 GMT", 64], true, true)
```

Here is what my chart looks like on loading the page...
[image: Initial HighChart]

Now here is what it looks like after addPoint...
[image: After addPoint]

**EDIT - Chart configuration added**

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
            load: requestInitialData
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: undefined
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                radius: 2
            },
            lineWidth: 2
        }
    },
    series: [], 
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 30,
        max: 150,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    }
}
```

**EDIT - Added JSFiddle** [Problem](https://jsfiddle.net/naqtkdLk/) Click button once to add initial data and then subsequent clicks to see the problem

***EDIT - Problem Solved*** It appears a bug was introduced into a recent version of HighCharts, since 4.2.2, which does work for me. 4.2.7 doesn't

Comment: Can post the whole object you have for highcharts ?

Comment: A jsfiddle reproducing the issue would be helpful (plot initial state, and add some button to add points)

Comment: @RC. [JSFiddle Reproducing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/naqtkdLk/). Sorry, I should mention that the first "Add Point" click loads the initial data while the subsequent button clicks add new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**...it was a bug in HighCharts 4.2.7 and possibly previous versions. Works in 4.2.2 though